# How to test when condition returns numeric(0) in R

Tags: r

Let's imagine you would like to construct a simple test based on the condition `setdiff(input, 1:9)`.

How can I construct an

```
if isnotempty(setdiff(input, 1:9)) stop ("not valid")
```

statement which stops execution when input is `c(3, 12)` but continues when input is `c(2,5,7)` say?
Many thanks,
Bertie

Comment: Checking if `input` is numeric would be nice here too. +1 to @TylerRinker for handling that too :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use `?length`:

```
isEmpty <- function(x) {
    return(length(x)==0)
}

input <- c(3, 12);

if (!isEmpty(setdiff(input, 1:9))) {
    stop ("not valid")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed this for the finishing touches of my Lottery generator ;) Bertie.

Answer (score 26):

Here's another option `identical(x, numeric(0))`.  Here's an example (basically took everything from sgibb and replaced the key line as I'm lazy):

```
isEmptyNumeric <- function(x) {
    return(identical(x, numeric(0)))
}

input <- c(3, 12)

if (!isEmptyNumeric(setdiff(input, 1:9))) {
    stop ("not valid")
}
```

Comment: I like how this is much more explicit (readable) and specific. For example, if `x = character(0)`, `length(x) == 0` returns TRUE while `identical(x, numeric(0))` returns FALSE.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following functions:

```
# 1. Check if 'integer(0)'
is.integer0 <- function(x) {
  is.integer(x) && length(x) == 0L
}

# 2. Check if 'numeric(0)'
is.numeric0 <- function(x) {
  identical(x, numeric(0))
}

# 3. Check is 'integer0' or 'numeric0'
is.int_num_0 <- function(x) {
  is.integer0(x) || is.numeric0(x)
}
```

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question in your subject line, but I think it is a better approach for what you are trying to achieve:

```
 if(!all(input %in% 1:9)) stop("not valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the isEmpty function. I propose the following, just in case you parse a vector, or a list:

```
isEmpty <- function(x) {
s<-sapply(x, function(y) length(y)==0, simplify = T)
return(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rlang::is_bare_numeric()`